# Unsigned int (primitive) and Integer (Object) usage in Java

Tags: java, unsigned-integer

I'm following [the Java tutorial on Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Early on, it states that

> In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2^32-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer.

What I'm understanding from this quote is that I can now store up to 2^32-1 as an int as long as I use the Integer wrapper object rather than the int primitive data type. But when I tried this out, my compiler is complaining that the value I'm using is too large, 2^31. I've tried this using both the primitive data type and Object.

```
Integer integerObjectLarge = 2147483648; //2^31
int integerPrimitiveLarge = 2147483648; //2^31
```

How exactly do I use an int/Integer to store unsigned value, such as 2^31?

Comment: Can you provide a source for the quote?

Comment: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Possibly silly question -> Do you have J8 installed?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it does say `-1`, which `2147483647` doesn't give any problems

Comment: Yes, I do. Double most recent update, and double checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I tried this out, my compiler is complaining that the value I'm using is too large, 2^31.

You have an error because the *literal* `2147483648` is syntactically invalid.

---

> How exactly do I use an int/Integer to store unsigned value, such as 2^31?

You can still perform unsigned arithmetic using the new methods of the [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) class, just don't use invalid literals:

```
int n = 2147483647 + 1;  // 2^31

System.out.println(Integer.toUnsignedString(n));  // treat int as unsigned
System.out.println(Integer.toString(n));          // treat int as signed
```

```
2147483648
-2147483648
```

---

> What I'm understanding from this quote is that I can now store up to 2^32-1 as an int as long as I use the Integer wrapper object rather than the int primitive data type.

You can *store* the unsigned int using the primitive type `int`, but using the value as an unsigned type requires you to use the utility methods of `Integer`, as can be seen above.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think Java has added a *true* unsigned 32-bit `int` type.  The only thing that's changed is that the `Integer` class now contains some methods that will treat a 32-bit integer(s) as an unsigned 32-bit integer.  See `compareUnsigned`, `divideUnsigned`, `parseUnsignedInt`, and several others in the javadoc for [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).  `Long` has some new methods too.

But basically, if you store the bit pattern (for example) `10001000_11110000_10010110_11000010` in an `int`, there's nothing in the `int` that says "This is an unsigned integer" or "This is a signed integer".  It depends on what methods you use to work with it.

Comment: Yeah, the Java language folks continue their tradition of obfuscating rather than elucidating.

Comment: I can understand why they might not have wanted to add a new primitive type.  But it just occurred to me that they could have added a new literal suffix without making anything else backward-incompatible or changing any other language rules, so that, say, `2147483649U` would be equivalent to the `int` `-2147483647`.

Comment: Yep, could have added the suffix (though it might require minor JVM changes).  And I suppose if you use `L` then you'd need a cast to keep the compiler from objecting.

Answer (score 2):

You've always been able to store "unsigned" integer literals by using hex:

```
 int x = 0xffffffff;
 // or any value >= 0x80000000;
```

This is because, for all practical purposes, the compiler thinks these are "signed".

You still can't assign a decimal value > 2^31 - 1 because it would create all sorts of backwards compatibility issues if this were suddenly allowed.